# how to Add an image in oracle 19c (PL/SQL) database using code-first approach dot net core

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I am trying to add an image into my oracle 19c (PL/SQL) database using entity framework code first approach.
I am accepting the data from client side as a byte array and assigning it to my model field

```
  [Column("Signature", TypeName = "BLOB")]
    public byte[] Signature { get; set; }
```

and then calling the add and save changes method however I get the following error

> InnerException = {"ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion
> requested"}

I tried to make the model datatype as

```
[MaxLength(65536)]
public string Signature { get; set; }
```

datatype for my model and also tried my luck with adding the following approach of adding

```
builder.Entity<SecUser>().Property(p => p.Signature).HasColumnType("image");
```

and `builder.Entity<SecUser>().Property(p => p.Signature).HasColumnType("Blob");`
on  `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)`
method in ApplicationDbContext

can anyone guide me on how how to add the image into the oracle 19c (PL/SQL) database

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved it required nothing more than just used a blob annotation for my model and I passed it a byte array turns out that you can only send files less than 32 Kb

```
[Column(TypeName = "BLOB")]
    public byte[] Signature { get; set; }
```